# Handle ActionForward in Struts 2

Tags: java, struts2, struts

I am migrating my Struts1 application to Struts2.

Is there any alternative for the below code in Struts2, I am using this in my Action classes.

```java
String path = mapping.findForward("failurePath").getPath();
new ActionForward(path);
```

Comment: For what purpose you are using this code in struts1

Comment: to redirect to below action class.
`<forward name = "failurePath" path = "/ShowFailure.do">`

Comment: Forward is not redirect, if you want an alternative do update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use in struts.xml

```
<result name="resultName" type="redirect" >failurePath.action?param1=${value1}&param2={value2}</result>
```

You need to have setter and getter methods for `value1` and `value2` oin action class

Comment: Its possible to pass params to the action, like `failurePath.action?message=Error`. In struts1 we can get the path and append the params in it, like `new ActionForward(path+"?message=Error");`

Comment: do have any reference for that ?

Comment: i set like that in my project

Comment: With the caveat that you actually want to use `redirectAction` if you're redirecting to an action.